# How do I make my TextView positioning responsive?

Tags: android, responsive-design, textview

[image]

In the image above, the black speech bubble and the red background behind it are a single `ImageView` that spans the width of a vertical phone screen. The "Hello" is a `TextView` and the layout is relative. Using margins, I was able to position the "Hello" inside the speech bubble in my Android emulator -- but the positioning is off when I emulate a different phone.

1. Is there a better way to position my `TextView`
2. is there a way to make it responsive (so that the Hello is always in
   the speech bubble, no matter what the device)?

**Here's my xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"> 

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainGraphic"
        android:src="@drawable/finished2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/enterValue"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/helloText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_marginEnd="29dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is that 9-patch image?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a **FrameLayout** instead of the **RelativeLayout** with same size like the image.
Then use the attributes `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` for the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
    <TextView
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/helloText"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mainGraphic"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainGraphic"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mainGraphic"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mainGraphic"
        android:gravity="center" />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use 9-patch image & set it as the background of the Textview. If you use a normal png file, we can't guarantee that it will align correctly on all resolutions & it can become blurred when stretched.

9-Patch image automatically resize to accommodate the contents of the view and the size of the screen.  Android SDK provides a tool for creating 9-patch images which is inside **SDK sdk/tools directory**. See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **9-patch** for the message shape. What you can do is make the root view of your layout as a *FrameLayout* and then add a *TextView* to it. Set the message shape Nine-patch as the background of the *TextView*.

For creating the 9-patch visit https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html by Roman Nurik. There just upload a png file of the image asset and choose the *xhdpi* definition for best results. The Nine-patch has 3 main properties -

**Stretch regions** : Defines which areas of the asset can stretch for accommodating different screen densities.

**Content Padding** : Defines the padding area for the content (text) that is going to appear inside the image.

**Optical Bounds** : Defines how much area should be optically visible around the asset.

Pros of using Nine-patches :

- Scalable
- Easy to use
- Lightweight
- Any amount of content can be put in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The 9-patch was tricky because it would only render at certain sizes (due to the relative layout?) and I still had to eyeball in the xml where the text should start within the patch. But it did improve the problem.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "it would only render at certain sizes (due to the relative layout?)" . You should not face any problem lacing the text in the root layout. Can you specify exactly what you are doing? Thanks

Comment: Here is a quick screenshot: http://imgur.com/DbYiS1Q. The text bubble wants to only be this size, or else fill up the entire screen width. Whereas I need it to be this width but 2/3 this height. But it will not resize this way.

Code: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/updatebackground"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

Comment: Nvm, the shape can be made more flexible using android:layout_margin

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should be using a complete red background to the RelativeLayout, and a black speech 9patch image for the TextView.
But if you really want the RelativeLayout to have background as red with speech bubble, you have to set it at run time.

Calculate the height and width of RelativeLayout at run time say `150px` and `300px` respectively.
Carefully look at the background image, and determine the edge points of bubble from top, right, bottom and left. For example, if image height is `100px` by `200px`, and bubble top starts at `30px` and bottom ends at `70px`, right edge starts at `150px` and left ends at `250px`. Also calculate the width and height of TextView.

At run time, change the position of TextView based on the above figures.